# How do I upgrade 19.04 to 19.10 when packages won't update?

Tags: 19.04

I can't seem to get these packages to upgrade which is preventing me from doing a release upgrade. How can I get around this?

```
apport/eoan-security,eoan-security 2.20.11-0ubuntu8.8 all [upgradable from: 2.20.10-0ubuntu27.3]
dbconfig-mysql/eoan,eoan 2.0.11ubuntu2 all [upgradable from: 2.0.11]
dovecot-lmtpd/eoan 1:2.3.4.1-5ubuntu3 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:2.3.4.1-1ubuntu2.4]
dovecot-mysql/eoan 1:2.3.4.1-5ubuntu3 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:2.3.4.1-1ubuntu2.4]
libbind9-161/eoan-security 1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:9.11.5.P1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.6]
libdns1104/eoan-security 1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:9.11.5.P1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.6]
libgnutls30/eoan-security 3.6.9-5ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.6.5-2ubuntu1.1]
libirs161/eoan-security 1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:9.11.5.P1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.6]
libisc1100/eoan-security 1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:9.11.5.P1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.6]
libisccc161/eoan-security 1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:9.11.5.P1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.6]
libisccfg163/eoan-security 1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:9.11.5.P1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.6]
libnss-systemd/eoan-security 242-7ubuntu3.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 240-6ubuntu5.8]
libpam-systemd/eoan-security 242-7ubuntu3.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 240-6ubuntu5.8]
librados2/eoan-security 14.2.4-0ubuntu0.19.10.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 13.2.6-0ubuntu0.19.04.4]
libsystemd0/eoan-security 242-7ubuntu3.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 240-6ubuntu5.8]
libudev1/eoan-security 242-7ubuntu3.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 240-6ubuntu5.8]
python3-apport/eoan-security,eoan-security 2.20.11-0ubuntu8.8 all [upgradable from: 2.20.10-0ubuntu27.3]
python3-apt/eoan-security 1.9.0ubuntu1.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.8.5~ubuntu0.3]
python3-venv/eoan 3.7.5-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.7.3-1]
systemd-sysv/eoan-security 242-7ubuntu3.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 240-6ubuntu5.8]
systemd/eoan-security 242-7ubuntu3.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 240-6ubuntu5.8]
udev/eoan-security 242-7ubuntu3.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 240-6ubuntu5.8]
```

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release

Comment: Yes, thank you both.